# "isPartOf" or "articleSection" for sections of a "TechArticle"

Tags: schema.org, structured-data

I'm preparing structured data (using Schema.org and JSON-LD) for a product documentation. Documentation pages are divided into 4 sections (CSS, Components, JavaScript, and Sections).

I use `TechArticle` to markup those pages.

Should I use `articleSection` or `isPartOf` to define where they belong to?

Comment: Do I understand it correctly that you want to use 4 `TechArticle` items per page, one for each section? And not 1 `TechArticle` for the whole thing?

Comment: One `TechArticle` per page (because 1 page = 1 article). But every single article belongs to a different section (as I mentioned, I have 4 of them). Example: Animations article, Parallax article, etc. belong to CSS section and Inputs article, Forms article, etc. belong to Components section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`articleSection`](http://schema.org/articleSection) property would be suitable.

The [`isPartOf`](http://schema.org/isPartOf) property would convey that the `TechArticle` is part of another creative work, but a category (like "CSS") isn’t a creative work. The page *about* such a category would be a creative work ([`CollectionPage`](http://schema.org/CollectionPage)), which could be used as value for `isPartOf` / where [`hasPart`](http://schema.org/hasPart) could be used, but on that page I’d prefer to use an [`ItemList`](http://schema.org/ItemList) (as [`mainEntity`](http://schema.org/mainEntity)) instead.

Comment: What if I have a tutorial for creating eg. Landing Page which is divided into 5 pages. Do I need an additional page where I describe that this tutorial has 5 parts in different pages?

Comment: @MichałT.KrawczykL: I think it would make sense to ask this in a new question.